# docker permissions issue writing to txt file with simple python script

Tags: python, docker

why do I need permission to write to a txt file? How do I solve this problem

main.py

```
text_file = open("sample.txt", "w")
n = text_file.write('some words dzfsadfadfs')
text_file.close()
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM rayproject/ray
ADD main.py .
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    text_file = open("sample.txt", "w")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'sample.txt'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the base image you're using (`rayproject/ray`) is configured to run as a non-root user (`ray`), but sets the working directory to `/`. There is a writeable directory `/home/ray` available; the easiest solution is probably adding an appropriate [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) directive to your Dockerfile:

```
FROM rayproject/ray
WORKDIR /home/ray
ADD main.py .
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

---

**Update**

I figured this out by first spawning a shell and checking what uid the process was running as:

```
$ docker run -it --rm testimage bash
(base) ray@bca6b7788820:~$ id
uid=1000(ray) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),27(sudo)
```

I checked the `passwd` file for information about that user:

```
(base) ray@bca6b7788820:~$ grep ray /etc/passwd
ray:x:1000:100::/home/ray:/bin/bash
```

And verified that directory was writeable:

```
(base) ray@bca6b7788820:~$ cd /home/ray
(base) ray@bca6b7788820:~$ touch foo
```

---

In general you can also figure things like this out by inspecting the corresponding Dockerfile, but for this particular base image that ended up being a bit of a pain because you need to track down a chain of dependencies:

- The immediate base image is `rayproject/ray`, and the Dockerfile is [here](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/docker/ray/Dockerfile).
- Which is based on [`rayproject/ray-deps`](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/docker/ray-deps/Dockerfile)
- Which is based on [`rayproject/base-deps`](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/docker/base-deps/Dockerfile)

And if you look at that last Dockerfile, you find:

```
USER $RAY_UID
ENV HOME=/home/ray
```

Comment: Great, thanks. How did you you know that there is a writable directory? where was that info?